# How to perform an action once every 1/2 second

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, timer

I want a XAML page to perform an action once every 1/2 second.

How would I do this?

I'm thinking that I could use a Timer that starts when the page is loaded and resets once it gets to 500 milliseconds, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

It doesn't have to be extremely precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DispatcherTimer for example. For sample code look at [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[Did You Know… That You Can Create A Timer Using XAML Animation?](http://jesseliberty.com/2007/12/09/did-you-know-that-you-can-create-a-timer-using-xaml-animation/)

Comment: I find storyboards a bit more accurate SL for WP7.